# Pagination problem

Tags: django, pagination, paginator

I'm using this code for my pagination, and I'd like the user's choice to be persistent throughout the site (this has been solved so far)...the only problem now is that the session variable now is permanent until the session is cleared by closing the browser.  Also, how can I get the adjacent pages displayed...like in the digg-style Django paginator.  I haven't been able to make sense of how to implement this into my code.

The code is as follows:

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, InvalidPage, EmptyPage

def paginate(request, object_list, paginate_by=10):
   try:
      if "per_page" in request.session:
        per_page = request.session["per_page"]
      else:
        request.session["per_page"] = int(request.REQUEST['p'])
        per_page = request.session["per_page"]
        request.session.set_expiry(0)
   except:
      per_page = 10

   paginator = Paginator(object_list, per_page)

   try:
      page = int(request.GET.get('page', '1'))
   except ValueError:
      page = 1

   try:
      items = paginator.page(page)
   except (EmptyPage, InvalidPage):
      items = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

   return items
```

Then in my template I have this to render the pagination links:

```
<div class="pagination" align="center"> 
 <span class="step-links"> 
  {% if items.has_previous %} 
    <a href="?page={{ items.previous_page_number }}">previous</a> 
  {% endif %} 
  <span class="current"> 
    Page {{ items.number }} of {{ items.paginator.num_pages }} 
  </span> 
  {% if items.has_next %} 
    <a href="?page={{ items.next_page_number }}">next</a> 
  {% endif %} 
 </span> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by enabling sessions.

I recommend reading through the chapter [Sessions, Users, and Registration](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter14/) on the djangobook website.

---

Edit: Now that you've enabled sessions, I think the problem is the hyperlinks in the template. Use an ampersand to separate multiple parameters in a url, for example

```
 <a href="?p={{ request.session.per_page }}&page={{ items.next_page_number }}">next</a>
```

---

Edit 2: I'm not sure if I understand what the problem is with the session expiry. The line that sets the session to expire when the browser closes is `request.session.set_expiry(0)`. See the django docs on [Using Sessions in views](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#using-sessions-in-views) if you want to change that.

To make a Digg style paginator, you need to write a function that takes the current page number and the total number of pages, and returns a list of page numbers. Then, in the template, loop through the page numbers and construct links to the pages.

A list of lists of page numbers would allow you to split the page numbers into groups, eg

`[[1,2], [20,21,22,23,24], [30,31]]`

Comment: thought so too...just wanted to know if there wasn't any other means

Comment: I've tried the above code but I must have gotten something wrong...now the pagination doesn't work (apart from the first page)...what have I missed or left out

Comment: I can't look at your code just now. If you mark the question as not answered (click on the green tick), and edit your question to explain what you've tried to do, it will probably get more attention from other people.

Comment: sadly it's still the same....the second page is never displayed.  The site is always on the first page no matter what

Comment: just solved it....removing ?p={{ request.session.per_page }}& works fine...the value for p will be set in the pagination anyway via the session

Comment: I've updated my question a bit...have a look at it and let me know